# jQuery Calender UI datepicker doesn't work when we click ESC key, calendar not working after 1st click on IE and Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, safari, calendar

When I click first on JQuery calendar it will display the calendar and if i select date it works smoothly. But When I press the Esc after displaying calendar instead of selecting date, it disappears but I cant get click next time onward.

It works fine in Chrome and Firefox but IE and Safari I cant click second time if i click on ESC after click on first time.

Is there anyone faced this problem? or any solution can suggest for this.

**I am using jquery-ui-calendar as below details.**

```
/*! jQuery UI - v1.11.4 - 2016-06-30
* http://jqueryui.com
* Includes: core.js, datepicker.js
* Copyright jQuery Foundation and other contributors; Licensed MIT */
```

Below is my JS code:

**/* This Section Custom Calendar*/**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // jquery date picker
    $(function () {
    if ($(window).width() < 768) {
        $.datepicker.setDefaults({
            changeMonth: false,
            changeYear: false,
            dateFormat: customFormat(),
            defaultDate: +0,
            minDate: 0,
            maxDate: '+364d',
            numberOfMonths: 1,
            showAnim: 'fadeIn',
            showButtonPanel: true
        });
    }
    else {
        // Set default datepicker options     
        $.datepicker.setDefaults({
            changeMonth: false,
            changeYear: false,
            dateFormat: customFormat(),
            defaultDate: +0,
            minDate: 2,
            maxDate: '+364d',
            numberOfMonths: 2,
            showAnim: 'fadeIn',
            showButtonPanel: true
        });

    }
    // Calendar 1 
    $(function () {
           $(function () {
                $('#arrivaldate').datepicker({
                onSelect: function (dateText, instance) {
                    var arrivaldateold = CleanDate($("#arrivaldate").val());
                    var arrdatenew = $.datepicker.parseDate(customFormat(), arrivaldateold);
                    var arrday = arrdatenew.getDate();
                    var arrmon = (arrdatenew.getMonth() + 1);
                    var arrYear = arrdatenew.getFullYear()
                    if (arrday.toString().length==1){arrday="0"+arrday;}
                    if (arrmon.toString().length==1){arrmon="0"+arrmon;}
                    var arrivaldatenew =  arrday + "/" + arrmon + "/" + arrYear;
                    $("#calendararr").val(arrivaldatenew);
                    // Populate checkout date field 
                    var nextDayDate = $('#arrivaldate').datepicker('getDate', '+3d');
                    nextDayDate.setDate(nextDayDate.getDate() + 1);

                    $("#arrivaldate").val(FormatDate(arrivaldatenew));
                    $('#depaturedate').datepicker('setDate',nextDayDate );
                    $("#depaturedate").val(ChangeDateFormat(nextDayDate));

                },
                onClose: function () {
                    $("#depaturedate").datepicker("show");
                }
            });
        });
        // Set checkout datepicker options        
        $(function () {
            $('#depaturedate').datepicker({
                // Prevent selecting checkout date before arrival:
                beforeShow: customRange
            });
        });
        function customRange(a) {
            var deptdateold = CleanDate($("#depaturedate").val());
            var deptdatenew =  $.datepicker.parseDate(customFormat(), deptdateold);
            var dptday = deptdatenew.getDate();
            var dptmon = (deptdatenew.getMonth() + 1);
            var dptYear = deptdatenew.getFullYear()
            if (dptday.toString().length==1){dptday="0"+dptday;}
            if (dptmon.toString().length==1){dptmon="0"+dptmon;}
            var departuredatenew =  dptday + "/" + dptmon + "/" + dptYear;
            $("#calendardept").val(departuredatenew);
            // changes done by parul starts for 30 days limit
            var SelectedDate = CleanDate($("#arrivaldate").val());
            var date1 = $.datepicker.parseDate(customFormat(), SelectedDate);
            var d = new Date();
            var diff = date1 - d;
            diff = (diff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
            var maxdiff = parseInt(diff);
            maxdiff = maxdiff + 31;
            var b = new Date();
            var c = new Date(b.getFullYear(), b.getMonth(), b.getDate());
            if (a.id == 'depaturedate') {
                if ($('#arrivaldate').datepicker('getDate') != null) {
                    //c = $('#arrivaldate').datepicker('getDate', '+3d');
                    b = CleanDate($("#arrivaldate").val());
                    c = $.datepicker.parseDate(customFormat(), b);
                    c.setDate(c.getDate() + 1);
                }
            }
            return {
                minDate: c,
                maxDate: maxdiff + "d"
            }  // changes done by parul ends
        }
    });
    $("#depaturedate").change(function () {

        var deptdateold = CleanDate($("#depaturedate").val());
        var deptdatenew =  $.datepicker.parseDate(customFormat(), deptdateold);
        var dptday = deptdatenew.getDate();
        var dptmon = (deptdatenew.getMonth() + 1);
        var dptYear = deptdatenew.getFullYear()
        if (dptday.toString().length==1){dptday="0"+dptday;}
        if (dptmon.toString().length==1){dptmon="0"+dptmon;}
        var departuredatenew =  dptday + "/" + dptmon + "/" + dptYear;
        $("#calendardept").val(departuredatenew);
        $("#depaturedate").val(ChangeDateFormat(deptdatenew));
    });

    $( "#c_checkout" ).click(function() {
       $("#depaturedate").datepicker("show");
    });

    $( "#c_checkin" ).click(function() {

       $("#arrivaldate").datepicker("show");
    });


    });
    var tomorrow = new Date();
    tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 2);
    var tomorrow = new Date(tomorrow).toLocaleDateString('en-GB', 
    {  
    day : 'numeric',month : 'short', year : 'numeric'
    }).split(' ').join(' ');

    $('#arrivaldate').val(tomorrow);

    var tomorrow = new Date();
    tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 3);
    var tomorrow = new Date(tomorrow).toLocaleDateString('en-GB', 
    {  
    day : 'numeric',month : 'short', year : 'numeric'
    }).split(' ').join(' ');



    $('#depaturedate').val(tomorrow);

}); //JQuery Document Ready Section   Finished Here
```